# Can't find classes with a very simple project

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm trying out php and decided to make a very simple program just to test class inheritance and learn the ropes of this language.

So, I have a main class which calls a class which implements an interface.
Simple, but when I run it he tells me he can't find the classes:

> **Fatal error**: Class 'PHPSTORM_META\Shape' not found in C:\Users\Paulo
>   Moreno\PhpstormProjects\test\Square.php on line 12

The thing is, that's precisely where that file is. The path is correct.

Here's the main code:

MainTest.php

```
<?php


echo "Hello World";
require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '\test\MainTest.php ';
require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/test/Square.php ';
require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/test/Shape.php ';
require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/test/GeoShape.php ';

echo "Hello World";


$rect = new Square(5, 5);

echo $rect->getArea();
echo "<br>" . $rect->getName();
```

The square class:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Paulo Moreno
 * Date: 4-12-2016
 * Time: 15:57
 */

namespace PHPSTORM_META;


class Square extends Shape implements GeoShape
{
    public $x;
    public $y;

    public function __construct($x, $y)
    {parent::__construct($this->name);
        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;
    }

    public function getArea()
    {
        return $this->x * $this->y;
    }
}
```

It's probably something very simple that will make me want to smash my head against a wall, but I'm stuck with this for quite some time. Yes, I am new to both php and phpstorm.

Comment: You include square before shape. The class square doesn't know yet what class shape is when you try to inherit it.

Comment: That was it Daan, thank you.

Comment: Remove `namespace PHPSTORM_META;` -- this namespace is for PhpStorm's own usage ONLY. I have no idea where you took this idea/code sample from (because `PHPSTORM_META` is very specific case) .. Try reading PHP manual first: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: Just as a side note, the [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) family of PHP statements **do not** copy-paste the code of the included file. They are processed during the runtime. In your case, when the script reaches the line `require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/test/Square.php ';` it loads and parses the `Square.php` file. In this file it finds the line `class Square extends Shape implements GeoShape` and attempts to use the class `Shape` and the interface `GeoShape`. It triggers an error and exits because it cannot find them (their files were not included yet).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces after the filenames:

```
require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '\test\MainTest.php';
require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/test/Square.php';
require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/test/Shape.php';
require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/test/GeoShape.php';
```

I also don't really understand why you would use backslashes in one of the filenames. I'd replace that with forwardslashes as well.

Also you need to include the namespace where you want to use the class

```
use PHPSTORM_META;
```

Comment: The slashes and the namespace were already attempts from me to solve the problem. 
the use namespace is a very handy tip by the way.
The problem was the order of the imports just like Daan explained in his comment.

Comment: @PauloMoreno ah yes, that makes sense. I just saw the spaces after the filenames and when I tested this on my machine it didn't work so I wanted to point that out.

Answer (score -2):

`dirname()` is function requires to define the path.Your problem is closing parenthesis. And `__DIR__` is magic constants to define the current directory of the file, SO try below code.

```
require_once __DIR__.'/test/MainTest.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/test/Square.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/test/Shape.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/test/GeoShape.php';
```

Comment: Actually it is enough to write `require_once __DIR__.'/test/Square.php';`... Your code is nonsensical, as it would try to `require_once` the whole directory - because that is what `dirname()` returns.